# file downloads based on user

Tags: views, files

My Goal 
 * User Request for a customize version of a file
 * admin uploads the file for that user.
 * User Downloads Files.

I am stuck at how to assign a certain file to certain user. How do i accomplish this with views . My idea was to create a node with file upload field and assign certain user to it , I dont know how to do this assign part and filter things with views

Note : i am using drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Drupal 7 you should be able to add a file field to a user.

Another solution would be a content type with a file filed. After creating the node of this new type make sure the receiving user is set as the owner. Finally make sure the user hass access to all files he owns.